# Replace array value multiple

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

After executing, i get the following result:

```
Array ( 
        [orderby] => post_date 
        [order] => asc 
      )
```

I want to replace the `orderby` and `order` value in this, so i can use them in a sorting system.

How can i do this ?
Thanks !

Comment: Please provide some code. You could edit the array values by using `$array['orderby'] = 'newValue'`

Comment: Why not just ? `$yourarray['orderby'] = 'somenewvalue';`

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite array values by setting them again, for example

```
$array['orderby'] = 'post_name';
$array['order'] = 'desc';
```

This way new string will replace old string in your array, just change your array variable name, i used `$array`, to fit your actual code